# Select customer if two conditions are met across multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to output customers who meet criteria in multiple columns across multiple rows.

Say this is my data:

| id | type | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hot | inside |
| 1 | cold | gym |
| 1 | medium | outside |
| 2 | cold | inside |
| 2 | cold | outside |
| 2 | hot | inside |
| 3 | hot | gym |
| 3 | cold | inside |
| 3 | medium | outside |

I want to keep customers who have type "medium" and event "gym." However, as you can see no customer has those in the same row. I want to keep only the customers and the rows that meet those criteria. So I want the results to look like:

| id | type | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cold | gym |
| 1 | medium | outside |
| 3 | hot | gym |
| 3 | medium | outside |

So it should drop the rows from each customer that do not meet one of the two criteria and drop all customers who do not meet both criteria.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question  and edit your question for a [mre]

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data.

Comment: A simple OR statement would likely do the trick. `WHERE type = "medium" OR event = "gym"`.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What if there was a customer that has only one row with e.g. `(medium, inside)`? Should that be returned as well?

Comment: @nbk - now edited. Simply using WHERE OR does not work because I only want customers who meet both the conditions, not just one of them. So I think I need some kind of grouping function?

Comment: @SebastianSmiley Simply using WHERE OR does not work because I only want customers who meet both the conditions, not just one of them. So I think I need some kind of grouping function?

Comment: @Steven Ah, I initially misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to count the rows for every id and the criteria

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "type" VARCHAR(6),
>   "event" VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO mytable
>   ("id", "type", "event")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'hot', 'inside'),
>   ('1', 'cold', 'gym'),
>   ('1', 'medium', 'outside'),
>   ('2', 'cold', 'inside'),
>   ('2', 'cold', 'outside'),
>   ('2', 'hot', 'inside'),
>   ('3', 'hot', 'gym'),
>   ('3', 'cold', 'inside'),
>   ('3', 'medium', 'outside');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable m1 
> WHERE ("type" = 'medium' OR "event" =  'gym') 
> and ((Select COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE "id" = m1."id" AND ("type" = 'medium' OR "event" =  'gym')  GROUP BY "id") = 2
> OR (Select COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE "id" = m1."id" AND ("type" = 'medium' AND "event" =  'gym')  GROUP BY "id") = 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | type   | event  
> -: | :----- | :------
>  1 | cold   | gym    
>  1 | medium | outside
>  3 | hot    | gym    
>  3 | medium | outside
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d896a072279cf4b3fdad50ab39b5de17)*

Comment: thanks for the response. I am a bit confused though as I need to keep customers who have both type=medium and event=gym, even if they are on different rows. This is just sample data for my problem which contains many more different combinations of "type" and "event".

Comment: sorry i remembered the question wrong, this now finds also when type and event are in the same row

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating two result sets, one that is customers that meet your first criteria, and another with customers that fit your second criteria, and then inner joining:

```
SELECT medium_customer.id
FROM (SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE type = 'medium') medium_customer
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE event='gym') gym_customer
    ON medium_customer.id = gym_customer.id
```

You could also use the INTERSECT operator to keep only records where two result sets match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM yourtable WHERE type='medium'
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM yourtable WHERE event='gym';
```

Another option is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourtable as yt
WHERE type='medium'
   AND EXISTS 
       ( 
          SELECT 1
          FROM yourtable
          WHERE yt.id = id
             AND event='gym'
       )
```

Lastly, you could aggregate and use a `HAVING` clause to keep records that fit the criteria:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourtable
WHERE type='medium' OR event='gym'
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Note that this will fail if a customer has more than one entry for `type='medium'` or `event='gym'`. In other words it's dependent on your data's uniqueness, so only use it if you are certain it won't generate false positives.